# django signals on user create

Tags: django

I have connected creating of user with the function create_user_profile, the problem comes when i create i user, i seems the connected functions is called twice and UserPRofile is trying to be created twice, witch fires an error

**column user_id is not unique**

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
column user_id is not unique
Exception Location: c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 234
Python Executable:  c:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
```

**here is the debug log:**

```
[13/Apr/2012 10:20:57] "GET /register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 176691
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.002) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."last_name" = favicon ; args=(u'favicon',)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.001) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."last_name" = testuser2 ; args=(u'testuser2',)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."username" LIKE testuser2@gmail.com ESCAPE '\' ; args=(u'testus
er2@gmail.com',)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.001) INSERT INTO "auth_user" ("username", "first_name
", "last_name", "email", "password", "is_staff", "is_active", "is_superuser", "la
st_login", "date_joined") VALUES (testuser2@gmail.com, , , testuser2@gmail.com, s
ha1$9bc1b$c9d377a1bf228ef74eb6931a9ed02d5c455e1576, False, True, False, 2012-04-1
3 10:21:13.949000, 2012-04-13 10:21:13.949000); args=(u'testuser2@gmail.com', '',
 '', u'testuser2@gmail.com', 'sha1$9bc1b$c9d377a1bf228ef74eb6931a9ed02d5c455e1576
', False, True, False, u'2012-04-13 10:21:13.949000', u'2012-04-13 10:21:13.94900
0')


====================================
=


DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.002) INSERT INTO "page_userprofile" ("user_id", "thum
b", "name", "title", "description", "phone", "birthday", "address", "lat", "lng",
 "gender", "creation_date", "updation_date") VALUES (13, , , , , , None, , , , ,
2012-04-13 10:21:14.131000, 2012-04-13 10:21:14.131000); args=(13, '', '', '', ''
, '', None, '', '', '', '', u'2012-04-13 10:21:14.131000', u'2012-04-13 10:21:14.
131000')
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.002) INSERT INTO "page_pagesettings" ("user_id", "bac
kground_url", "background_repeat", "showAvatar", "showTags", "color_background",
"color_panel_background", "color_panel_background_opacity", "color_name", "color_
title", "color_description", "color_links", "font_name", "font_title", "font_desc
ription", "font_tags_and_links", "font_size_name", "font_size_title", "font_size_
description", "font_size_tags_and_links", "can_contact_via_email", "panel_positio
n") VALUES (13, , 0, False, True, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , True, ); args=(13
, '', u'0', False, True, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', True, '')


====================================
=


DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.002) INSERT INTO "page_userprofile" ("user_id", "thum
b", "name", "title", "description", "phone", "birthday", "address", "lat", "lng",
 "gender", "creation_date", "updation_date") VALUES (13, , , , , , None, , , , ,
2012-04-13 10:21:14.442000, 2012-04-13 10:21:14.442000); args=(13, '', '', '', ''
, '', None, '', '', '', '', u'2012-04-13 10:21:14.442000', u'2012-04-13 10:21:14.
442000')
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "page_userprofile"."id", "page_userprofil
e"."user_id", "page_userprofile"."thumb", "page_userprofile"."name", "page_userpr
ofile"."title", "page_userprofile"."description", "page_userprofile"."phone", "pa
ge_userprofile"."birthday", "page_userprofile"."address", "page_userprofile"."lat
", "page_userprofile"."lng", "page_userprofile"."gender", "page_userprofile"."cre
ation_date", "page_userprofile"."updation_date" FROM "page_userprofile" LIMIT 21;
 args=()
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1 ; args=(1,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 2 ; args=(2,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 4 ; args=(4,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 5 ; args=(5,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 7 ; args=(7,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 8 ; args=(8,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.001) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 9 ; args=(9,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.001) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 10 ; args=(10,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 11 ; args=(11,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 12 ; args=(12,)
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.000) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 13 ; args=(13,)
[13/Apr/2012 10:21:15] "POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 446959
DEBUG:django.db.backends:(0.001) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."username",
 "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_us
er"."password", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."is_
superuser", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."last_name" = favicon ; args=(u'favicon',)
```

**Connection:**

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print('')
        print('')
        print('=========================================')
        print('')
        print('')
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        PageSettings.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**creating the user:**

```
newUser = User.objects.create_user(username, username, password)
 newUser.last_name = slug

 if(registerAs == 'company'):
   newUser.first_name = 'company'
 else:
   newUser.first_name = 'user'

 #newUser.save()
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `dispatch_uid` argument to give your signal a unique identifier.

```
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid="create_user_profile")
```

For more information see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals).

Comment: This is for preventing signals from being *connected* multiple times; it will still *fire* multiple times if the action *occurs* multiple times.

Comment: But the profiles are only created if [`created`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) is `True`. `created` will be `False` for subsequent saves.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid the problem by adding an additional sanity check to your method:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and not UserProfile.objects.exists(user=instance):
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        PageSettings.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: While I think this sanity check would work, I think its better to address the underlying problem (that the `create_user_profile` receiver function was being registered twice) by specifying `dispatch_uid`.